# Datatable vs Dataset

Tags: c#, dataset, datatable

I currently use a DataTable to get results from a database which I can use in my code.

However, many example on the web show using a DataSet instead and accessing the table(s) through the collections method.

Is there any advantage, performance wise or otherwise, of using DataSets or DataTables as a storage method for SQL results?

Comment: If you're working with web apps, you may want to consider using a DataReader: http://aspnet.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/050405-1.aspx http://aspnet.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/051805-1.aspx http://www.devx.com/vb2themax/Article/19887/1954?pf=true

Comment: Ultimately, DataTable and DataSet were useful transitions from ADO RecordSet ... back in 2002. You should not bake them your primary data metaphor these days.

Comment: @MarcGravell What would you suggest as a primary data metaphor these days?

Comment: @m_a_s explicit t - classes, typically; perhaps "records" in c# vNext

Answer (score 104, accepted):

It really depends on the sort of data you're bringing back.  Since a DataSet is (in effect) just a collection of DataTable objects, you can return multiple distinct sets of data into a single, and therefore more manageable, object.

Performance-wise, you're more likely to get inefficiency from unoptimized queries than from the "wrong" choice of .NET construct.  At least, that's been my experience.

Answer (score 34):

One major difference is that DataSets can hold multiple tables and you can define relationships between those tables.

If you are only returning a single result set though I would think a DataTable would be more optimized. I would think there has to be some overhead (granted small) to offer the functionality a DataSet does and keep track of multiple DataTables.

Answer (score 9):

in 1.x there used to be things DataTables couldn't do which DataSets could (don't remember exactly what). All that was changed in 2.x.  My guess is that's why a lot of examples still use DataSets.  DataTables should be quicker as they are more lightweight. If you're only pulling a single resultset, its your best choice between the two.

Comment: AFAIK one big one was that a DataTable couldn't be serialized and couldn't be returned as a result from a WebService.

Answer (score 6):

One feature of the DataSet is that if you can call multiple select statements in your stored procedures, the DataSet will have one DataTable for each.

Comment: You can also run multiple SQL select queries in one SQLCommand and access each resultset in dataset.Tables[i]

Answer (score 3):

There are some optimizations you can use when filling a DataTable, such as calling BeginLoadData(), inserting the data, then calling EndLoadData().  This turns off some internal behavior within the DataTable, such as index maintenance, etc.  See [this article](https://blogs.objectsharp.com/post/2004/04/18/How-can-I-improve-the-loading-of-my-datasets.aspx) for further details.

Answer (score 1):

When you are only dealing with a single table anyway, the biggest practical difference I have found is that DataSet has a "HasChanges" method but DataTable does not. Both have a "GetChanges" however, so you can use that and test for null.

Answer (score 0):

A DataTable object represents tabular data as an in-memory, tabular cache of rows, columns, and constraints. 
The DataSet consists of a collection of DataTable objects that you can relate to each other with DataRelation objects.