# what can be best - Dataset or datareader?

Tags: asp.net, database, ado.net

I have stock market application which  will be frequently used by millions of members at a time.
What could be the best option to retrieve data from my database based on the retrieval time and Database load  - **`DataReader`** or **`DataSet`**?

Comment: how to do that? sorry i dont knw plz help

Comment: and Deepa, while you are at it, just scroll down this page to see the related questions asked. -1 exact duplicate. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083193/whats-better-dataset-or-datareader

Comment: @Mitch, @Furqan: to be fair i only see two of her questions worthy of getting marked as answer.

Comment: @ naveen: that's 2 that could presumably be accepted?

Comment: @mitch Wheat: yep. thats true. i think the problem is that she don't know how to ask a question :) @Deepa: http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: Also, if you are about to write software that can handle "millions of members at a time." you shouldn't have to ask these types of questions. Seriously.

Comment: @Mitch Wheat: My thought exactly!

Comment: thanks all. i hope will take care of criteria to ask questions.

Comment: @Deepa:+1 undone the negative voting. there is always a first time. :)

Comment: thanks for editings and reverting negative vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you will have a large amount of people reading the data, then you should use the DataReader paradigm.  This way you can quickly get in and out with the trouble of schema inference.  I would also recommend that once you pull the data from the server that you cache it.  Even if it is only cached for 1 second, that will improve the number of connections from the database that will retrieve the same data.  Otherwise, you could quickly saturate your connection pool if you are not careful as well as some possible locking.