# ADO.NET – DataReader(Connected) vs DataSet(Disconnected) 

Tags: c#, ado.net

I working with a big database what is the best way in performance -connected mode or disconnected mode- should I use?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083193/whats-better-dataset-or-datareader. do check duplicates for posting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

quoted from the post specified above: [What's better: DataSet or DataReader?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083193/whats-better-dataset-or-datareader)

> It depends on your needs. One of the most important differences is
>   that a DataReader will retain an open connection to your database
>   until you're done with it while a DataSet will be an in-memory object.
>   If you bind a control to a DataReader then it's still open. In
>   addition, a DataReader is a forward only approach to reading data that
>   can't be manipulated. With a DataSet you can move back and forth and
>   manipulate the data as you see fit.

Hope this helps