# Postgresql works in disconnected mode?

Tags: postgresql, ado.net

I'm curious if Postgresql supports disconected mode with dataset architecture like ado.net?

Connected mode works faster but is large resource consumer.

Comment: You seem to be referring to something like http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorial/AdoDotNet/lesson05  right? Can you provide a better reference for what you're talking about? When you ask a group who know about product X if they can do something like the AB feature on product Y, they're probably not going to know what the AB feature is, so it helps to *explain it* and *provide references*, so they know "aaah, that's similar to our EF feature..."

Comment: It looks like in disconnected mode the ADO.NET system must fetch and cache the data. If it can run SQL against it then it must have an embedded subset of the database engine embedded in the driver/adapter to allow that. For example, it might use embedded MS-SQL to work with an MS-SQL server offline.

There is no embedded version of PostgreSQL, so that approach cannot work. Maybe it can load PostgreSQL data into an embedded MS-SQL, SQLite, or something for offline work, but I really doubt it ... and if it did, it couldn't cope with PostgreSQL dialect data types and queries.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/15564485/398670 which suggests that you should really be using something like Entity Framework and a connection pool instead. That *will* work with PostgreSQL.

Comment: I've found [Npgsql.EF6 2.0.12-pre4](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Npgsql.EF6/2.0.12-pre4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a [good article about dotConnect for PostgreSQL](https://www.devart.com/dotconnect/postgresql/articles/tutorial_ef.html)

Entity framework and ADO.NET for PostgreSQL.