# hangs on datagridview .fill large amount of data

Tags: vb.net

Hello I am trying to fill a datagridview with items from a datafile. The code stops on the .fill . I tested the query in excel (Microsoft query) it works fine there. I also tested it (in my vb code) by adding a WHERE to only receive on specific entry, this works fine. Any ideas how to get this to work in my application? Code is below thanks for the help!

```
Dim dataAdapter As New Odbc.OdbcDataAdapter()

Private Sub ChangeSelect()

    Dim selectCommand As String = "SELECT CWIPH.CUST_NO, CWIPH.JOB_NO, CWIPH.JOB_NAME, CJCMS.JOB_DESC FROM { OJ CWIPH CWIPH INNER JOIN CJCMS CJCMS ON CWIPH.JOB_NO = CJCMS.JOB_NO }"

    accessDB(selectCommand)
End Sub

Private Sub accessDB(ByVal selectCommand As String)
    Dim JobConnectionString As String = "Dsn=Jake; provider=System.Data.Odbc"
    Dim cn As OdbcConnection = New OdbcConnection(JobConnectionString)
    Dim table As New DataTable()
    cn.Open()

    Dim cmd As New Odbc.OdbcCommand(selectCommand, cn)

    Me.dataAdapter = New Odbc.OdbcDataAdapter(cmd)

    With dgvWorkOrder

        .AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells

        .AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.ColumnHeader

        .AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.ColumnHeader

    End With

    Dim commandBuilder As New Odbc.OdbcCommandBuilder(Me.dataAdapter)

    Me.dataAdapter.Fill(table)
    Me.dgvWorkOrder.DataSource = table

    cn.Close()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This article helped a lot. [What's better: DataSet or DataReader?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083193/whats-better-dataset-or-datareader) 
So I ended up changing my code to use data reader and so far so good.