# Return multiple recordsets from stored proc in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, datatable, dataset

I am having to convert an ASP classic system to C#

I have a stored procedure that can return up to 7 recordsets (depending on the parameters passed in).

I need to know how I can simply return all the recordsets as individual DataTables so that I can loop through whatever is there, skipping to the next DataTable when I get to the end of it without having to run multiple SQL statements and use multiple adapter.Fill statements to add each table into a DataSet.

In classic it was a simple Do While not objRS.EOF loop with a objRS.NextRecordset() when I got to the end of the loop to move to the next statement.

Is there anything I can use that doesn't require a total rewrite of the current back end code?

Each recordset has a different number of columns and rows. They are unrelated to each other. We return multiple recordsets from Stored Proc's to reduce traffic.

Examples would be nice.

Thanks

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
SqlConnection con=new SqlConnection("YourConnection String");
SqlCommand cmd=new SqlCommand();
SqlDataAdapter da=new SqlDataAdapter();
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
cmd = new SqlCommand("name of your Stored Procedure", con);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
//cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SuperID", id);//if you have parameters.
da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
da.Fill(ds);
con.Close();
```

After this you can take advantage of different (7) recordsets using

```
ds.Tables[0]
ds.Tables[1]
ds.Tables[2]
ds.Tables[3]
ds.Tables[4]
ds.Tables[5]
ds.Tables[6]
```

Comment: Thanks, I like this answer purely because I already have a data class with wrapper functions that handle connections and dispose of them when the class is destroyed etc. I just wanted to use an existing function which I had and reference the tables within the dataset.

Answer (score 10):

If you fill a DataSet using the `SqlDataAdapter.Fill()` Method then each of your recordsets returned from the stored procedure will be returned as a DataTable within your dataset

```
DataSet dataset = new DataSet();
using (var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("yourStoredProcedure", yourConnectionString))
{
    adapter.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    adapter.Fill(dataset);
}
for (int i = 0; i < dataset.Tables.Count; i++)
{
    // Do something for each recordset
}
```

If you use a SqlDataReader then use can use the `SqlDataReader.NextResult()` method to advance to the next recordset:

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(yourConnectionString))
using (var command = new SqlCommand("yourStoredProcedure"))
{
    connection.Open();
    using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            // do something with first result set;
        }
        if (reader.NextResult())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                // do something with second result set;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return;
        }
        if (reader.NextResult())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                // do something with third result set;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I never knew that you could get multiple result set with `SqlDataReader` with `.ExecuteReader()` and `.NextResult()`. Thanks for the detailed answer!

Comment: Indeed you can, I generally prefer working with the SqlDataReader due to the lower memory usage by only storing the current record, and not bothering with what has already been read, and what is yet to be read. However there is a great analogy in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1083223/1048425) comparing datasets with datareaders.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the SO link! I have used `SqlDataReader`s in the past and I thought that it was a lot of code to maintain. I then tried `DataTables` and thought that they were much quicker. I will have to keep the alternatives in mind when writing additional code in the future! Again, thanks for sharing!

Comment: this is what we call a perfect solition

Answer (score 7):

this will return you all you need

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(connString))
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
    {
        cmd.CommandText = "yoursp";
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        conn.Open();

        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        adapter.Fill(ds);

        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is what I use to get multiple recordsets from a stored procedure. Just for clarification, the recordsets are stored in `ds.Tables` and you may want to place the `DataSet ds = new DataSet();` at the beginning so that you can reference it outside of the `using (SqlConnection conn = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(connString))` block. Just a thought.

Comment: yes you can move it out. just giving an example of how to do it;.

Answer (score 0):

you can check if dr has any more recordset ot no by using  **`if (dr.NextResult())`**

and then loop again with dr.read

try this

```
string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConString"].ConnectionString;
SqlConnection Con = new SqlConnection(connStr);

try
{
    string str1 = "select productid,productname from products;select VendorFName from vendor";
    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(str1, Con);

    com.Connection.Open();

    SqlDataReader dr = com.ExecuteReader();

    DropDownList1.Items.Add("Select Product Id");
    DropDownList2.Items.Add("Select Vendor Name");

    while(dr.Read())
    {
        DropDownList1.Items.Add(dr.GetValue(0).ToString());
    }

    if (dr.NextResult())
    {
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            DropDownList2.Items.Add(dr.GetValue(0).ToString());
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
}
finally
{
    if (Con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
    {
        Con.Close();
    }
}
```