# MS SQL Server: Access a local temporary table in a prepared statement

Tags: c++, sql-server, qt, sql-server-2008-r2, prepared-statement

### Problem statement

I am trying to create and fill a local temporary table, which works well now, but I can not access the table and its contents from pepared queries afterwards.

A very simplified version of the problem, which already reproduces the issue (C++0x with Qt5 framework):

```
// fyi: this constructor overload already executes the given query string
QSqlQuery query1("IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM SYSOBJECTS WHERE ID=OBJECT_ID('#tmp') AND XTYPE='U') DROP TABLE #tmp", _db);
QSqlQuery query2("SELECT * INTO #tmp FROM mytable WHERE 1 = 0", _db);

// so far, so good: the table gets dropped if it was already existing and gets recreated with the schema of 'mytable'; it is empty due to the '1 = 0'

// this works: some code for inserting data
QSqlQuery query3("INSERT INTO #tmp SELECT mytable WHERE ...", _db);

// this also works: i can select some data
QSqlQuery query4("SELECT count(*) FROM #tmp WHERE col = 1234", _db);
Q_ASSERT(query4.hasNext());

// fails at exec() with error: "unkown object name '#tmp'"
QSqlQuery query5(_db);
query5.prepare("SELECT count(*) FROM #tmp WHERE col = :boundVar");
query5.bindValue(":boundVar", 1234);
query5.exec();
```

What do I miss here? I already had a hard time getting the queries for creating the temporary table to run until I read this in the [SQL Server documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms130779%28v=sql.110%29.aspx):

> In SQL Server 2005, the prepared statements cannot be used to create
>   temporary objects [...], such as temporary tables. These procedures
>   must be executed directly.

This is already quite confusing, as I am using SQL Server 2008r2 - whereas the documenation which is written for Server 2012 only mentions the 2005 version and older. Nevertheless, I tried to perform the queries for creating the table without preparing and it worked (see code example). The quote does not say anything about *accessing* the temporary table via a prepared statement, however.

### Requirements

I have to use a local temporary table due to performance reasons: quite a large dataset will be filtered and transformed and inserted into the temp table, where about 10 queries will follow and use this materialized intermediate data. TVPs are not a good option as it slows down the following queries drastically. The overhead of creating a temp table is really paying off several times over in my case. Furthermore, a local temporary table would be very much preferred over other solutions as they are isolated against other connections and will be cleaned up after disconnect, which is just what I want.

There are many reasons why I can not go without prepared statements for reading from the table, so I really hope someone can help me with this one.

### Actual question

How can I read data from my local temporary table (from within the same connection that created it of course) with a prepared query?

Thanks a lot for any idea/solution!

Comment: Instead of running 5 separate queries from your application, can you put them all in a stored proc and just run the stored proc from the app?   That way they would all run in the same context on the DB, and the temp table would persist.

Comment: You have to be in the same SQL Server session, not client session. If you change it to ##tmp (this would last longer-its a global temp table) other sessions could see it but as soon as the session that created it ends it would have no more sessions using it so it would go away too. I would do what Tab suggests.

Comment: @Tab Alleman: those 10 queries will each select huge data sets from different tables, it is just that they use that same session-local prefiltered data from the temp table, how would I return this in a single stored proc?

Comment: @benjamin moskovits: wouldn't other users and connections also see the ##tmp table then? They must be isolated from each other and may not delete the table of another process.

Comment: @PhilipDaubmeier stored procedures can return multiple result sets

Comment: @Kritner: very interesting indeed. I dont think this will be a solution for me though, as the query gets built quite dynamically and can not be moved into a stored procedure easily - and to make matters worse, we have to support Sqlite as well, which doesn't support stored procs at all.

Comment: Other users would see a global temp table as long as it exists. The only solution that can work is to invoke a stored proc (per Tab Alleman's suggestion). Kritner's suggestion that procs can return multiple result sets is for all practical purposes wrong. If you are willing to convert back and forth to and from XML yes otherwise no - http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/620635/Stored-procedures-and-multiple-result-sets-in-T-SQ

Comment: @benjamin moskovits: thanks for your ideas so far. Do you know if it is impossible to access temp tables in prepared stmts by definition or do you think it should be possible in principle?

Comment: I don't know what a prepared statement is.

Comment: @benjaminmoskovits that article is incorrect.  I know for a fact you can access multiple result sets from a stored procedure in at least c# and coldfusion, as I've had to do it.  Additionally: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18510901/return-multiple-recordsets-from-stored-proc-in-c-sharp

Comment: Could you please show me a SQL Server Proc that returns multiple result Sets (tables). There is a thing called MARS but what I am stating is that you cannot invoke a  SQL Server stored procedure and get multiple sets returned. You can have logic that returns different sets based on parameters but not multiple sets from a single stored procedure.

Comment: @benjaminmoskovits it can be done.   In .NET you access the multiple resultsets as DataTables that are members of the DataSet that is returned by the SqlCommand, if I remember correctly.  If a proc has two SELECTS, the first one produces DataTable[0] and the next produces DataTable[1].

Comment: If you have a ' select  * from table a; select * from table b'in your SQLcommand and use MARS it can work. You are not invoking a stored procedure and you are probably using two sessions so they wont see each others temp tables. If someone can create a stored procedure that returns multiple tables I would love to see it.

Comment: @PhilipDaubmeier, I think most of the people answering you are more SQL-fluent than c++.   Like Benjamin said, temp tables only persist within a single SQL context (user-session).   I don't know what the different c++ methods do as far as persisting a session or starting a new one.   If prepared statements always operate in their own session, then they will never, in principle, be able to access local temp tables created outside the prepared statement.

Comment: You will not be a good corporate citizen if you persist sessions from the client side. You want to invoke a session, let SQL Server do its thing and finish as quickly as it can,return something and release all the sessions resources for the next task.

Comment: @benjaminmoskovits not really sure how to provide an example of that as it would require both SQL and front end, and I only know how to provide an example of one at a time (SQLFiddle or dotnetfiddle) so how to integrate them together, I'm unsure of.  Here's an article on doing it, though it is not an ideal solution as you lose out on strongly typed objects.  https://scriptbucket.wordpress.com/2012/07/23/returning-multiple-result-sets-from-a-sql-stored-procedure-for-use-in-a-c-application/

Comment: The firewall I am behind is blocking the URL. You have to go through all kinds of compromises to have  SQL Server proc return something that looks like multiple data sets so unless there is no other way I would start with the assumption that its not realistic to expect a SQL Server proc to return multiple data sets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about putting all this in a stored procedure, and the stored procedure creates a real table prefixed with the date and time, and the user id.

So roughly

CREATE TABLE someuser_190320151830....

Build dynamic sql statements as above to populate the table

SELECT whatever from table so your app can use it

DROP TABLE someuser_190320151830

The final step could be to select the data then drop the table.

Unless the same person manages to run it at exactly the same time it could work.  I have used a similar approach but it is in something run quite infrequently.

Comment: If he uses a real table instead of a temp table, then it shouldn't matter if he calls a stored proc or executes all the queries from c++ actually.  The table will persist until explicitly dropped.  If he uses a GUID to generate the table name, he won't have any concurrency issues.

Comment: Thanks for your idea. However, I don't really like the fact that those tables have to be cleaned up manually. If the connection is lost or the programm gets terminated during the executing the table will get stuck and the database gets crowded with orphaned tables. And what is more, temporary tables were introduced for this exact reason, so I would really want to use that feature.

Comment: Accepted your answer - thanks for your help. See my answer for the concrete solution I implemented now.

Answer (score 0):

### Concrete solution

After much testing and experimenting, and with the ideas of [user1683641](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1683641/user1683641) and [Tab Alleman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1507566/tab-alleman) I combined everything to something that finally does the job and meets all my requirements:

- I am using global temporary tables now, as those are visible between the scope of non-prepared and prepared queries
- Global temporary tables get cleaned up when the client application gets closed without an explicit `DROP` and even if it is terminated or the connection is lost
- I postfix those tables with a unique GUID, which is safe from collisions of combinations of users and timestamps

Minimal example:

```
QString const tableName(QString("##tmp_%1").arg(QUuid::createUuid().toString()));

// clean up, prepare empty table and fill with intermediate data
QSqlQuery query1(QString("IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM SYSOBJECTS WHERE ID=OBJECT_ID('%1') AND XTYPE='U') DROP TABLE %1").arg(tableName), _db);
QSqlQuery query2(QString("SELECT * INTO %1 FROM mytable WHERE 1 = 0").arg(tableName), _db);
QSqlQuery query3(QString("INSERT INTO %1 SELECT mytable WHERE ...").arg(tableName), _db);

// works now! I can now select the temporary data perfectly fine from prepared statements
QSqlQuery query4(_db);
query4.prepare(QString("SELECT count(*) FROM %1 WHERE col = :boundVar").arg(tableName));
query4.bindValue(":boundVar", 1234);
query4.exec();
```

Thanks to all for your input! I will accept [user1683641](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1683641/user1683641)s answer as it lead me to this.

Comment: I have run into a similar problem. I would very much like to use your solution. However, it is still unclear to me as to how using Global temporary tables solves the problem. i.e, even if you postfix those tables with a unique GUID,  wouldn't it be still visible to other connections and users ? and wouldn't other users be able to run queries on it ? (which wouldn't have been the case had it been a local temporary table). Correct me if I am missing something ?

Comment: @Mohammed Raqeeb: yes, the tables are visible for other connections and users, but that is not a problem as the GUIDs will not collide, so no other application instance of any user will use/query the table. Also, there are no confidential values in there, only a filtered set of a table that is already visible to all users of the database.