# Stored procedure to return multiple sets VS multiple stored procedures for each set

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, vb.net

I have a table that connects to multiple other tables.

```
Quote
QuoteBuyingRate
QuoteChargesDetail
QuoteDisclaimer
```

I can

1. select the data I need from all 4 of these using multiple stored procedures
2. select the data with multiple select statements inside the one stored procedure

Besides design preference or opinion, are there any true technical pros/cons to using one or the other? Performance concerns?

Comment: No significant performance concerns that I know of.

Comment: I personally like option b, but instead of 4 separate select statements, the main procedure would call the 4 child procedures.  This option creates only one connection and one database call each time you need to populate an entity/object.  So I would have a stored procedure called usp_Quote_Load_All that calls 4 other procedures, usp_quote_select, usp_quotebuyingrate_select, etc.

Comment: A single proc cannot return 4 seperate tables - it can return one table that is a result of a union or multiple inserts (which require the same column list). So if they are all the same I would go with (b) so you only have to invoke the proc once.

Comment: @benjaminmoskovits sure a stored proc can return multiple result sets. It is quite simple, just have more than 1 select statement in your procedure.

Comment: @benjaminmoskovits not sure what you are working with, but with ms sql server this can be done. I know at least 2005+ can do this.

Comment: @benjaminmoskovits http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18510901/return-multiple-recordsets-from-stored-proc-in-c-sharp

Comment: can someone share a working proc that does multiple selects?

Comment: @benjaminmoskovits it is written exactly how you think you would be, just put multiple select statements in a stored proc.. also pretty easy to find via google search. go check it out. good luck.

Comment: What I meant was how would a calling program handle the different tables being returned? Unless they are using MARS in a .net program?

Comment: @benjaminmoskovits I have a custom data access objects that populates a dataset from each result set returned from a stored procedure. It makes this pretty painless. Remember that some of the MS procs have multiple returns also.

Comment: You just proved my point. Its not easy (many production sites will not allow DAO from within SQL Server) to use and its not really inherent to TSQL.

Comment: @benjaminmoskovits Just to be clear about working with multiple result sets: MARS is a very specific application of them that allows for executing additional commands while retrieving the results. This is not the same thing as simply having multiple result sets to cycle through. Unrelated to MARS, it is rather easy to access additional result sets in .NET using either `SqlDataReader.NextResult()` or filling a `DataSet` which will then contain 1 table per result set. However, as you just mentioned, dealing with multiple result sets in pure T-SQL is far from easy.

Comment: i dont want to engage any moe on this topic. Answering users (who may not be very advanced developers) to solve problems by using advanced features may not be the best answer. Most of the people asking questions on this forum want a TSQL based solution.

Answer (score 1):

From the absolute surface, no there is very little reason to go one way or the other. Assuming that the calls are not made multiple times a minute the difference between multiple calls and a single call is irrelevant. It absolutely doesn't matter unless the number of calls are high.

So if you come up with a reason it is better architecture either way for your use case, go with that. If you don't have anything pushing you either way, just do it in a one stored proc for simplicity, and a slightly more efficient network transfer.

Now if you start to have conditional logic or other complexity in order to have them all in one call, you are causing potential query plan caching problems, and could affect your scalability.

Comment: you touched on a little of what i was asking with "Assuming that the calls are not made multiple times a minute the difference between multiple calls and a single call is irrelevant." ... I have been searching around looking for some documentation of this but can't find any. Do you have any reference or are you just pulling this from your mental knowledge base?

Comment: It's from a good amount of personal experience. The absolute best way to see how inefficient or efficient something is however it's to measure it. Profiling code and dB calls will give you hard numbers for your personal environment and call volume/frequency. Having said that, assuming a decent connection from db to app server, the connection time especially when using connection pooling like . net does by default, is a really small component of the overall cost of execution.

Answer (score 0):

How are these tables connected? If your tables have primary keys and are connected by foreign key constraints, then you might not need to run multiple stored procedures or return multiple result sets from a single stored procedure. A single stored procedure returning a single result set might be sufficient if you can take advantage of JOINs.