# EF Stored procedure result set and total count

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures

The below stored procedure return the filtered result set and the total records.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_Employee_Search]
(
@LastUpdatedDate DATETIME = NULL,
@PageNo INT = 1,
@PageSize INT = 25,
@SortColumn NVARCHAR(20),
@SortOrder NVARCHAR(4) = 'ASC'
)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE

@lSortCol NVARCHAR(20),
@lFirstRec INT,
@lLastRec INT,
@TotalCount INT

SET @lSortCol = LTRIM(RTRIM(@SortColumn))

SET @lFirstRec = ( @PageNo - 1 ) * @PageSize
SET @lLastRec = ( @PageNo * @PageSize + 1 )

; WITH ResultsCTE
AS (
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY
CASE WHEN (@lSortCol = 'EmployeeId' AND @SortOrder='ASC') THEN [EmployeeId] END ASC,
CASE WHEN (@lSortCol = 'EmployeeId' AND @SortOrder='DESC') THEN [EmployeeId] END DESC
) AS ROWNUM,
Count(*) over () AS TotalCount,
[EmployeeId]
FROM [dbo].[Employee]
WHERE
(@LastUpdatedDate IS NULL OR [UpdatedDate] > @LastUpdatedDate)
)

SELECT * INTO #Results FROM ResultsCTE

SELECT @TotalCount = (SELECT count(*) FROM [dbo].[Employee])

SELECT
[EmployeeId]
FROM #Results AS Results
WHERE ROWNUM > @lFirstRec AND ROWNUM < @lLastRec
ORDER BY ROWNUM ASC

RETURN @TotalCount

END



GO
```

When I import the same to EF, I found that the return type is only the integer.

```
 using (TM_Entities db = new TM_Entities())
            {
                db.usp_Employee_Search(
            }
```

Also I did not see any complex type Model for this stored procedure in Model Browser of EDMX

I would like to know how to get the employee data and also the total count in EF

Comment: I believe there is some issue with resultsets from temporary tables when using EF; I'm not 100% with EF so I'm sure there is someone here that can give you a better answer but it might give you a pointer

Comment: Possible related: [Return multiple recordsets from stored proc in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18510901/4519059) ;).