# how to assign option string containing <br> to editions value attribute of jqGrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

In my jqGrid I am defining editable column with edittype :'select'. I am using inline editing. I want to assign option element to this drop down with string

for example

```
1:SA<br>21;2:SH<br>22;3:GT<br>23
```

When I assign such string to value attribute of editoptions of this column I am getting option element in drop down as follows
SA
undefined
undefined
SH
undefined
undefined
GT
undefined
undefined

Can anybody suggest me how to overcome this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose that your problem can be solved by usage `delimiter` property which replace default `;` separator used by jqGrid to any another symbol, for example to `?` in the code below:

```
editoptions: {
    delimiter: "?",
    value: "1:SA&lt;br&gt;21?2:SH&lt;br&gt;22?3:GT&lt;br&gt;23"
}
```

Of cause you should replace additionally `<br>` to some encoded version like `&lt;br&gt;`.

**UPDATED**: [The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SelectWithHtmlData.htm) demonstrate that above suggestion works.

Comment: Hi with this I am able to searate the option element correctly but the option text get created like SA &lt;BR&gt;

Comment: @Shaggy: I can' t reproduce the problem which your describe. See **UPDATED** part of ma answer with working demo.

Comment: Actually I was replacing the <BR> tag from server side string.Replace() which was causing <BR> to get replaced as &amp;ltBR&amp;gt. So i tried it replacing from javascript which worked perfectly for me. Thanks For your support.

Comment: One more problem I would like to share with you [here] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21230875/jqgrid-datatable-not-rendered-properly-in-ie8-with-jqgrid-version-4-5-4). Its related to jqGrid 4.5.4 compatibility with IE8 browser.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do a replace on the `<br>` and make them `\n`

see [this guys](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5499821/1876355) answer, maybe you can use his code to do the replacement

Look at [JQuery's](http://api.jquery.com/html/) `.html()`, you will also be able to use that.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I need to show there <br> tag. I don't want content after br tag to be arear on new line. I tried replacing < with &lt; & > with &gt; but by ; jqGrid treats it as new option element to create.