# DataGridView + SQL Server without using a DataSet

Tags: .net, sql-server, datagridview

I am reading that DataSets aren't almost never the best choice. But when I searched code examples for populate a DataGridView I realized that in amost all of the examples DataSet are used.

So is there a better way? or have I to use DataSets?

For if you need, I want to use the DataGridView to select, insert and update data from a table in SQL Server.

Comment: Use DataReader.Datasets are preferred if you want to manipulate the data after its fetched from the DB.The performance difference is negligible for a few thousand records.Here more information http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083193/whats-better-dataset-or-datareader

Comment: @inquisitive_mind with a DataReader can I Insert, Select, Update and Delete data direclty from sql server?