# Are there any differences if I'm retrieving data in a DataSet instead of a DataTable

Tags: c#, .net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Datatable vs Dataset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2250/datatable-vs-dataset)

I want to know the difference in terms of memory, efficiency if I'm using `DataSet` instead of `DataTable` to fill data.

I want to explain this to a third party so strong reason needed.

Comment: If you're retrieving just a single table, then using a `DataSet` is just unnecessary overhead - in terms of memory and performance

Answer (score 3):

`DataSet` is an in memory representation of database which contains a collection `DataTable` and `DataRelation` object is used to relates these tables.
On the other hand, `DataTable` represents an in memory data cache for any "single" table  of database.

So if you are dealing with only single table then its better to use `DataTable` instead of `DataSet`

Answer (score 0):

DataSet can hold multiple DataTables and datasets maintain some internal indexes to improve performs for things like finds and selects.

Some interesting discussions

[How can I improve the loading of my datasets](http://blogs.objectsharp.com/cs/blogs/datasetfaq/archive/2004/04/18/367.aspx)

[Datatable vs Dataset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2250/datatable-vs-dataset)

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the sort of data you're bringing back. Since a DataSet is (in effect) just a collection of DataTable objects, you can return multiple distinct sets of data into a single, and therefore more manageable, object.

Performance wise dataset transferring takes more time than datatable since dataset is a collection of datatable

[see this for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2250/datatable-vs-dataset)

Comment: Not just a collection of `DataTable` - a DataSet also contains the data relations and even more overhead

Comment: DataSet's are memory hungry. Do not use them if the DataTable's in question don't have any relationships between them.