# How is a datatable different from a dataset and datareader?

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Datatable vs Dataset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2250/datatable-vs-dataset)

Can someone please explain the difference to me or point me in the right direction? When should you use one over the other? What are differences?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2250/datatable-vs-dataset

Comment: Not much on datatable on google.

Comment: [datatable +.net](http://www.google.com/search?q=datatable+&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&client=firefox-a&hs=a9r&rls=org.mozilla:en-US%3Aofficial&source=hp&q=datatable+%2B.net&pbx=1&oq=datatable+%2B.net&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=5856l5856l2l6324l1l1l0l0l0l0l239l239l2-1l2l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=b79c18b8972b8076&biw=1280&bih=905)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

a datatable represents tabulated data just like a database table.  a dataset is synonymous with a database; it contains  datatables, relationships etc. a datareader is a forward only row by row reader that requires an open connection. you can fill a datatable with a dataadapter.  for reading look up ADO.NET.