# Where to use dataset and datareader. What is recommended

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net, datareader

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's better: DataSet or DataReader?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083193/whats-better-dataset-or-datareader)

I have gone through the basics (advantage and disadvantages) of the data set and data reader. But for my application which should i use. If it requires lots of data to be retrieved. I can do this by both way. So the question is that which is appropriate?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083193/whats-better-dataset-or-datareader and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2250/datatable-vs-dataset

Comment: @Eric Lennartsson : first link helpful for me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you execute just select on your queries, you can use `ExecuteDataReader`

in order to increase your performance.

Link MSDN about performance report : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms978388.aspx