# Getting output from return type DataSet and displaying it in a Gridview

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, dataset

I am trying to get the output from a method with return type as DataSet and using it in a GridView but the output is not reflecting.
Can anyone please advice how to get the output.

```
  public DataSet GetData()
{
    try
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            conn.Open();
        }

        String sql = "Select top 100 * from SEQUENCE";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet output = new DataSet();

        adapter.Fill(output);
        conn.Close();

        return (output);     

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(),
                   "ServerControlScript", ex.Message, true);

        return (null);

    }
}




    Home home = new Home();
    Output=home.GetData();
    GridViewOutput.DataSource = Output.Tables["Out"];
    GridViewOutput.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try moving where you declared `output` and returned it, to as shown bellow.

I changed the part where you declare the grid views data source. You should be able to just declare the datasets datasource as the method itself.

Have a look at this thread on dataset vs datatable [Datatable vs Dataset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2250/datatable-vs-dataset) 
A DataSet can hold multiple tables. However if you're just returning a single results set a DataTable rather than a DataSet would probably make more sense.

Just change the Methods type to a DataTable. Declare it's source the same way as shown bellow.

```
public DataSet GetData()
{
    //Move where you declare output ot here
    DataSet output = new DataSet();
    try
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            conn.Open();
        }

        String sql = "Select top 100 * from SEQUENCE";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);


        adapter.Fill(output);
        conn.Close();



    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(),
                   "ServerControlScript", ex.Message, true);

        return (null);

    }
     //And move the return to here 
     return output;
}



    //Should just need this to display the data
    GridViewOutput.DataSource = GetData();
    GridViewOutput.DataBind();
```

One final thing when using SQL in c# I tend to use the `using` statement. It makes the code a lot cleaner and handles the disposing of resources for you see [When should I use the using Statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10057334/when-should-i-use-the-using-statement) . Your code would look like this if you choose to use it:

```
 public DataTable GetData()
   {
      //Move where you declare output ot here
      var output = new DataTable();

      using (var conn = new SqlConnection())
      {


         try
            {
                conn.ConnectionString = //Your DataBase Connection;

                String sql = "Select top 100 * from SEQUENCE";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
                cmd.commandType = commandType.Text;


                Var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);


                adapter.Fill(output);



            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(),
                           "ServerControlScript", ex.Message, true);

                return (null);

            }
             //And move the return to here 
             return output;
       }
  }          


   //Should just need this to display the data
   GridViewOutput.DataSource = GetData();
   GridViewOutput.DataBind();
```